# SwiftUI HStack with equal Height

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want the `Text("111")` to have the equal height of the `VStack` containing 2222... and 333....

```
struct Test7: View {
  var body: some View
  { HStack (alignment: .top) {
    Text( "111")                     // Shall have equal Height
    .background(Color.red)
    VStack(alignment: .leading){.    // of this VStack
      Text("2222222")
      .background(Color.gray)
      Text("333333333")
      .background(Color.blue)
    }
  }
  .background(Color.yellow)}
}
```

I tried with a `GeometryReader`but didn't get it to work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is possible approach using `.alignmentGuide`

[image: demo]

```swift
struct Test7: View {
    @State
    private var height: CGFloat = .zero // < calculable height

    var body: some View {
        HStack (alignment: .top) {
            Text( "111")                     
                .frame(minHeight: height)    // in Preview default is visible
                .background(Color.red)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {    
                Text("2222222")
                    .background(Color.gray)
                Text("333333333")
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { d in
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // << dynamically detected - needs to be async !!
                    self.height = max(d.height, self.height)
                }
                return d[.top]
            })
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Note: real result is visible only in LivePreview, because height is calculated dynamically and assign in next rendering cycle to avoid conflicts on @State.

Answer (score 0):

use .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

```
var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text("111")
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("2222222")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                        
                Text("333333333")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
        }.background(Color.yellow)
            .frame(height: 50)
    }
```

result: [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTALj.png)

Comment: only works with fixed height of the parent. Not what OP was asking for