# Fill Rectangle without disturbing the geometry of HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to fill the black Rectangle on the left to fit the height of the red and blue color combined.

Basically, the black color instead of being in the middle like this,

[image: Container]

Should be filled to occupy the remaining space.

```
HStack(spacing: 1) {
            
            Color.black
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            
            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 1) {
                
                Color.red
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                Color.blue
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: try to adjust the aspectRatio of black View , will give you a result. Color.black.aspectRatio(0.49, contentMode: .fit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is probably the simplest approach...

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 1) {

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.clear
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Color.clear
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .overlay(Color.black)

        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 1) {
            Color.red
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Color.blue
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternate approach with alignment guides was provided in my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346544/12299030.

Alternate approach with view preferences was provided in my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63165931/12299030.

Comment: So basically I want to apply this logic to Images. Just like if there are a number of images in a posted tweet, It shows a grid below giving some insight about the images it holds. I'm looking for a solution that uses a geometry reader to do that. So if I have 3 images, regardless of whatever size, there should be a static grid in which one image should take the lef portion and the other two stacked vertically just like above colors.

Comment: You don't need GeometryReader for that. You already has have grid and can use each of above colors (which can be .clear) as holder for overlaid images (fill, clipped, borders, etc. are optionals).